# Docker Compose : Percona XtraDB Cluster Bootstrapping

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, percona-xtradb-cluster

I need some help. How can I bootstrap a **Percona XtraDB Cluster** on a docker-compose as 1st node?

I have this **my.cnf** file

```
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera3/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=pxc-cluster
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.56.15,192.168.56.20,192.168.56.25
wsrep_node_name=pxc1
wsrep_node_address=192.168.56.15
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=xtrabackup:1q2w3e4r
pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING
!include /etc/mysql/node.cnf
```

and **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    percona-xtradb-cluster:
        container_name: pxc_node
        image: 'percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - CLUSTER_NAME=pxc-cluster
            - XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD=1q2w3e4r
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
            - 4567:4567
            - 4568:4568
            - 4444:4444
        volumes:
            - /etc/percona.d/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
```

run **sudo docker-compose up -d**

Answer (score 1):

according to [manual](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/install/docker.html), it seems you should start 2nd and 3rd servers only after 1st server is started, so, with your docker compose it should be something like this

```
version: '2'
services:
    percona-xtradb-cluster:
        container_name: pxc_node
        image: 'percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - CLUSTER_NAME=pxc-cluster
            - XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD=1q2w3e4r
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
            - 4567:4567
            - 4568:4568
            - 4444:4444
        volumes:
            - /etc/percona.d/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf

    percona-xtradb-server1:
        depends_on: 
          - percona-xtradb-cluster
        container_name: pxc_node1
        image: 'percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - CLUSTER_NAME=pxc-cluster
            - CLUSTER_JOIN=pxc_node
            - XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD=1q2w3e4r
        volumes:
            - /etc/percona.d/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf

    percona-xtradb-server2:
        depends_on: 
          - percona-xtradb-cluster
        container_name: pxc_node2
        image: 'percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:5.7'
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - CLUSTER_NAME=pxc-cluster
            - XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD=1q2w3e4r
            - CLUSTER_JOIN=pxc_node
        volumes:
            - /etc/percona.d/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
```

Notice `depends` fields - they are important - [see documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on)
And see `CLUSTER_JOIN=pxc_node` present, they indicate what server to join

Comment: im running this in multi host, 3 servers (3 nodes)

Comment: its impossible to achive with docker-compose.yml, since it is aimed to work only single docker host. i think you need to consider using docker-swarm - https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/, since it allows to make deployment on fleet of separate servers using nearly same docker-compose yml files